# can solve this error ? ( NoReverseMatch )

Tags: django, rendering, reverse, url-parameters, templatetags

I'm ratherly amatour in django and cant solve this problem,

error:
NoReverseMatch at /blog/

```
Reverse for 'single' with keyword arguments '{'pid': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: \['blog/(?P\<pid\>\[0-9\]+)\\Z'\]
```

urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from blog.views import \*
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

app_name= 'blog'

```
urlpatterns = \[
path('',home,name='home'),
path('\<int:pid\>',single, name='single'),
\]
```

views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Post
import datetime

def single(request,pid):
single_post= Post.objects.filter(pk=pid)  
def counting_single_views(n):
n.counted_views += 1
n.save()
counting_single_views(single_post)
context = {'single_post':single_post}
return render(request,'blog/blog-single.html',context)
```

def home(request):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
posts= Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte= now)
context={'posts':posts}
return render(request,'blog/blog-home.html',context)
```

blog-home.html :

```
{% for post in posts %}
\<a href="{% url 'blog:single' pid=post.pk %}"\>\<h3\>{{post.title}}\</h3\>\</a\>
\<p class="excert"\>
{{post.content}}
\</p\>
{% endfor %}
```

i tried with id instead of pk , but no differ,

Comment: Check your `post.pk ` is not empty. If you pass a empty value in URL it will show you error.

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace? The error says it's missing the `pid` argument in the link. But in your `blog-home.html` everything looks great. Maybe you've another url for example `<a href="{% url 'blog:single' %}">Another URL</a>`

Comment: post.pk is not empty  and post include , context 
{'posts': <QuerySet [<Post: test title 1 - 1>, <Post: test from admin - 3>]>}, and i want to load 'blog:home' and then 'blog: single' but it cant load.

Comment: how can share stactrace  here, its too long

Comment: should be path('<int:pid>/',single... take care of the slash position outside <>. And post.pk is empty according error message (at least one of them)

Comment: I do it but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In your url file

```
path('\<int:pid\>',single, name='single'),
```

Replace  it with

```
path('<int:pid>',single, name='single'),
```

and also note  [#Manoj Kamble] point that can also happen

Answer (score 0):

i got my answer,
infact i didn't change any of url tag,
i used

```
 {% url 'blog:single' pid=post.pk %}
```

but in 'base.html' used

```
{% url 'blog:single' %}
```

i changed this and NoReverseMatch solved. thanks everyone.